# Different result with the same search keyword on search all files

Tags: community, chatter, file-storage, content-search, files

Am having some problem with search (number 3 in picture below).

[image]

I have two users, one from country A and another from Country B

When country A do a search on **search all files**, for eg testing file, he get a certain result.

But when same search is performed by country B, a different result is obtained.

**Why does the same search having same profile in different locations return different results?
Any possible causes?**

Thanks for your reply.